# Creating Global Array in in xPages using SSJS

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a custom control having a but submit and multiple SSJS libraries. I have require a global array initialized in in submit button and array values are populated from different libraries. I have declared and initialized an array button but its not available in libraries. Any clue how can I declare an array as global to make this available for all libraries? If not than how an array can be created using scope variables?

Please guide me . Thanks in advance

Best Regards,

Qaiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define it as a viewScope array - this question ... [xPages repeat control with scoped variable as data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661783/xpages-repeat-control-with-scoped-variable-as-data-source) .. isn't directly about that, but shows how to define an array via viewscope.

essentially for a one-dimentional array, it would be:

```
viewScope.myArray=["1","2","3"];
```

You can define it in the  event on thye xpage :

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.myArray = ["1","2","3"];}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I will try and get back to you on this.

Comment: I used viewScope.myArray = [];   viewScope.myArray.push("1st Val");viewScope.myArray.push("2nd Val"); viewScope.myArray.push("3rd Val");  It worked for me.